# can't get CALayer containsPoint to work

Tags: iphone, calayer

I've got an array of CALayers containing images which can be moved around by the user, and i'm trying to use containsPoint to detect if they have been touched - the code is as follows:

```
int num_objects = [pageImages count];

lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self];

CGRect objRect;
CALayer *objLayer;

for (int i = 0; i < num_objects; i++) {

    objLayer = [pageImages objectAtIndex:i];
    objRect = objLayer.bounds;

    NSLog(@"layerPos:%@, layerBounds:%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(objLayer.position), NSStringFromCGRect(objRect));
    NSLog(@"point:%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(lastTouch));

    if ([objLayer containsPoint:lastTouch] == TRUE) {
        NSLog(@"touched object %d", i);
        return i;
    }
}
```

The information i'm outputting puts the touch within the bounds of the layer (i've assumed position is the centre of the layer, i haven't altered the anchor point. The layer hasn't been rotated or anything like that either), but containsPoint: doesn't return true. Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong, or suggest a different/better way to achieve what i want?

Comment: have you used UIView's touchesMoved delegate method here.?

Comment: try replacing the if statement as this-    if ([objLayer containsPoint:lastTouch])

Comment: i am using touchesMoved to generate lastTouch (just cut that line out from it to make it a bit more readable). touch position is correct, i was previously doing this using the position and height/width of the image, which worked okay, but i need to check against the layer as the images can be rotated. taking out the == TRUE has no effect :(

Comment: one more approach,try this way too.   instead of using containsPoint in if condition use this if condition   if([CGRectContainsPoint(objRect, lastTouch)]).replace the if statement and check

Comment: CGRectContainsPoint: does indeed do the job, although you have to do a bit more work before to convert the bounds of the layer to be a rect in the correct place rather than a rect with origin (0,0). thanks for the pointers efrank :)

Comment: nice to listen that your problem solved. can u try replacing the if statement as :if ([objLayer.superLayer containsPoint:lastTouch] == TRUE) {, i want to know whether we can approach in this way too..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So .. found the problem - the point needs to be converted from superlayer coordinates in order to work with the layer containsPoint:

replace

```
if ([objLayer containsPoint:lastTouch] == TRUE) {
```

with

```
if ([objLayer containsPoint:[objLayer convertPoint:lastTouch fromLayer:objLayer.superlayer]] == TRUE) {
```

You can mess about with the co-ordinates yourself and use CGRectContainsPoint: (see comments above), but this is a simpler solution so i get to answer my own question for the first time. big tick for me, yay!